# WPF Documentation and Visual Studio 2008 Express

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, documentation, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to get a WPF development environment set up at home, using Visual C# Express 2008. I installed both it and the MSDN documentation for it, however it looks like the documentation doesn't include any WPF documentation.

I was about to install the Windows Vista SDK, however it looks like that only includes the documentation for .NET 3.0, not 3.5 SP1. Where can I download the documentation for .NET 3.5SP1 and (ideally) have it integrated with the documentation that I already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly hidden on Microsoft's Express Editions site is the link to the [complete MSDN library download](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/msdn/Default.aspx). You want the second entry ("MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008").

Comment: Ahh, that would do it. Apparently the web install link on the main download site doesn't install close to everything. Thank you very much. :)